# Running OSGi Applications on WSO2 platform

Tags: osgi, wso2

My organisation is moving away from traditional EAR/WAR based applications and moving towards OSGi for building our business applications.  The WSO2 platform provides a lot of support services (esb, governance, identity, etc) that we would want to leverage in our applications.

Is it possible to deploy our OSGi components directly to the WSO2 application server, or does it make more sense to deploy just to WSO2 carbon?  Are there any issues that we should be considering with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 Carbon is the Core server for WSO2 platform which includes all common features used as the base for WSO2 products. Application Server is Carbon Server + Service Hosting features and few others which is used for service hosting aspect. You can use Carbon Server directly to deploy OSGi bundles. You can install any of the features you need through configure-->features
by just adding a P2 repository. if you do not need Service hosting features just start from Carbon server and add any features you need to fulfill your need. (feature is a collection of OSGi bundles which cater one aspect). You can build your p2 repository and install your features directly to Carbon Server as it is normally done. There are several methods to drop your OSGi bundle into WSO2 Carbon based servers.

Following [link](http://wso2.org/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2) will help you to understand How OSGi is used inside Carbon Server.

Comment: This [webinar](http://wso2.org/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components) is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 A.S. is based on a Carbon platform, like every other WSO2 instances, so it should not make much difference, but makes sense to use the Application Server.

I have not tried to deploy OSGI components but I know it is possible. Sorry I can't help more.